# Using a generic SObject in VisualForce Page

Tags: visualforce, sobject, wrapper-class

I have a wrapper class that I want to reuse for Both Accounts and Contacts

```
public class SelectableSObject{
    public Boolean selected {get; set;}
    public SObject obj {get; set;}
}
```

In the constructor something like this...

```
selectableAccounts = new List<SelectableSObject>();
for(Account acc : [SELECT Name FROM Account]){
   SelectableSObject so = new SelectableSObject();
   so.selected = false;
   so.obj = acc;
   selectableAccounts.add(so);
}
```

When I try to bind a field in visual force:

```
<apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:dataTable value="{!selectableAccounts}" var="a">
        <apex:column >
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!a.selected}" />
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headervalue="Account Name" value="{!a.obj['name']}"/>
    </apex:dataTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

I get a non-descriptive compile error:

> Read access denied for null  (Line: 1)

Seems like this should be possible, but maybe its not?

Comment: can you post your pageblock/ repeat / datatable and how you populate the a variable?Are you trying to get the name field  of the sobject?

Comment: @rao done.  I'm just trying to access the name field as an example.  Get the same error if I try to access Id or any other fields as far as i can tell.

Comment: @Ralph, I have never used Apex and VF before its my first day and I am given a task to finish in a week time... If you dont mind can you explain me your example. So I can start woking on my task. Thank you so much for the example at the first place.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This works fine for me.  Ran a couple tests and all of the below work.

### VF Page

```
<apex:page controller="GenericTest">
    {!test['name']}
    {!test1.obj['name']}
    <apex:repeat value="{!testList}" var="test2">
        {!test2.obj['name']}
    </apex:repeat>
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!testList}" var="test3">
            <apex:column>{!test3.obj['name']}</apex:column>
            <apex:column value="{!test3.obj['name']}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

### Controller

```
public with sharing class GenericTest {

    public Sobject test { get; set; }
    public Wrap test1 { get; set; }
    public List<Wrap> testList { get; set; }

    public GenericTest() {
        test = new Account(name = 'asdf');
        test1 = new Wrap();
        test1.obj = test;
        testList = new List<Wrap>{ test1 };
    }

    public class Wrap {
        public SObject obj { get; set; }
    }
}
```

### Output

[image]